# Trouble setting "Theme.Material3.DayNight.*" in style.xml

Tags: android, material-ui

I am following the [implementation steps](https://m3.material.io/components/navigation-drawer/implementation) for Navigation View from Material3. Among the instruction, there is the following:

> In res/values/themes.xml:
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.*">
> <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
> </style>
> ```

**However**, I am getting an error in Android Studio saying that `"Theme.Material3.DayNight.*"` can not be resolved.
[image]

According to the auto-complete, I could pick a specific value after the `.`
[image]

**But**, the instructions are very specific with the `*`.

**How to get that to work?**

Comment: You're not meant to use a literal asterisk. It's just indicating that it works for any of the themes based on `Theme.Material3.DayNight`, whichever specific one you pick.

Comment: Thank you. That came to my mind, as you can see when I checked for my options, but I thought the documentation would at least give a more explicit hint about the idea on `*`